# Return null or zero when no value is found

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @t1 table (ID char(3) not null,Name char(5) not null)
insert into @t1(ID,  Name) values
('ID1','Test1'),
('ID2','Test2'),
('ID3','Test3')


declare @t2 table (ID char(3) not null)
insert into @t2(ID) values
('ID1'),
('ID2'),
('ID3'),
('ID4'),
('ID5')

SELECT id, name from @t1
WHERE id in (SELECT id from @t2)
```

This returns:

```
id  name
ID1 Test1
ID2 Test2
ID3 Test3
```

How could I get this code to return the the values for ID4 and ID5 as zero or null (ideally zero)?  Like this:

```
id  name
ID1 Test1
ID2 Test2
ID3 Test3
ID4 NULL
ID5 NULL
```

With the solution provided I used ISNULL to return 0 instead of NULL.

Comment: Why would you want a zero in a column that has `Test###` strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT @t2.id, @t1.name from @t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN @t1 ON @t1.ID = @t2.ID
```

As opposed to an `INNER JOIN` an `OUTER JOIN` will take **all** rows from the source table instead of only those that also exist in the joined table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @t2.id, @t1.name 
from @t2
left join @t1 on @t1.id = @t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT aa.id,
       b1.name
from @t2 aa
LEFT JOIN @t1 b1 ON(aa.ID=b1.id)
```

Comment: Please add explanation about the key aspects of the one-statement solution that you have provided.

Answer (score -1):

Use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT t1.id, COALESCE(t1.name, 0) 
FROM @t1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN @t2 t2
ON t2.id = t1.id
```

`COALESCE` will return the first non-null value in the argument list so if `t1.name` comes out as `NULL` then it will return `0` in its place.

Comment: Why the downvote? This does **exactly** what the OP asked: They wanted to have zero for the last two IDs rather than `NULL` if possible.